# How to show loading progress bar for image in IOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, image-processing, uiimageview, uiprogressview

I am creating one book reader Application. In my application I am loading the pages as images from Web URL.When loading each images I like to show the loading percentage like[image] below

Please suggest me some ideas

Answer (score 2):

Here are few opensource controls that might help you

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/koaprogressbar

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mcprogressbarview

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/advprogressbar

Answer (score 2):

I've made an open source progress view that is pretty customizable, and will be even more so in its upcoming 2.0 release. You can find it at [lightdesign/LDProgressView](https://github.com/lightdesign/LDProgressView). Please let me know if it suits your needs or how it might be changed to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at NSURLConnectionDataDelegate (protocol of NSURLConnection).
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate

You need to implement the following method:

(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite

In order to support this kind of behaviour.

Comment: I am using EGO Imageview weather its possible to show loading in that library?

Comment: I don't know that library, but as long as it use NSURLConnection, it's possible. All you have to do, is implement this method..